# Why the action of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ on the standard representation preserves a quadratic form?

Tags: representation-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras

In the representation theory book by Fulton and Harris, it is proven that Sym$^2V\cong \Gamma_{2,0}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ where $V$ is the standard representation of $\mathfrak{g}_2$. I did not read the proof in detail. My question is how does this isomorphism imply that the action of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ on $V$ preserves a quadratic form?

Comment: Does it follow from the fact that $V$ is the unique irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ of its dimension. Therefore $V\simeq V^*$. We also have a rather universal bijective correspondence between $Hom(V\otimes W,U)$ and $Hom(V,Hom(W,U)$ (sorry, its name escapes me at the moment - I really should review homological algebra one of these years). Apply that to $W=V, U=\Bbb{C}$. Presumably it factors via $Sym^2(V)$.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas. My upvote to  your answer is already there.

Answer (score 3):

We get from that isomorphism a nonzero morphism of representations $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)\to \Bbb C$. We know that morphisms $V\otimes V\to \Bbb C$ correspond to bilinear forms on $V$ preserved by $\mathfrak g_2$. The corresponding bilinear form is symmetric if and only if the map factors over $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$, by the defining relations of $\mathrm{Sym}^2$. Thus a nonzero morphism $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V) \to \Bbb C$ corresponds to a symmetric bilinear form on $V$ preserved by $\mathfrak g_2$ or equivalently, a preserved quadratic form.